# How to get the original source when using CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

When I use this plugin in my razor view form MVC, the web page showed me an error message that says:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

I would like to know if is there a way to configure this plugin to get only the source code instead of the HTML code transformed.

I mean:

What I'm getting

```
<p>some text </p>
```

What I want (non html generated)

```
some text
```

Is there a way to get that?

Comment: So.. If there is "<p>Foo</p><p>Bar</p>" Do you want "FooBar" or "Foo\nBar" or...? If you just have one paragraph in CKE and you want the text it contains why even use CKE and not just a textarea? Also, "get only the source code instead of the HTML" - this does not match your I mean example. The HTML is the source code. Try to clarify the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/849

it should resolve your error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.editable().getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try stripping html tags after getting html of current instance of editor as below:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getData().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```